# UnsatisfiedLinkError with gwt-test-utils in DOMImplStandard

Tags: java, gwt, junit, gwt-test-utils

I want to write a gwt-test-utils test to test the composite widget I created. After spending some time getting started, the JUnit test is finally starting up, I can initialize the widget and even access private fields.

However here is the show stopper: my widget uses another widget which extends `ComplexPanel`. Whenever I try to call its `insertChild` method, I get the following exception

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard.insertChild(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;I)V
>     at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard.insertChild(Native Method)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplMobileSafari.insertChild(DOMImplMobileSafari.java:26)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.insertChild(DOM.java:958)
>     at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ComplexPanel.insert(ComplexPanel.java:203)
>         [...]

I read about gwt-test-utils' Patcher API and took a look at its source code. `DOMImplStandard` extends `DOMImpl`. There is a PatchClass for `DOMImpl` with a PatchMethod for `insertChild` (`DOMImplUserPatcher`). But for some reason the patching does not seem to work for me. I tried writing my own patch for `DOMImpl.insertChild` which resulted in

> com.googlecode.gwt.test.exceptions.GwtTestPatchException: 2 @PatchMethod methods detected for the same target...

After that I wrote a patch for `DOMImplMobileSafari.insertChild` and that did work! But I do not want to copy `DOMImplUserPatcher` just to apply it to `DOMImplMobileSafari` and still think that something is not working as expected for me.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?